# Event listener works in on context but not another - code identical, and no errors observed. Possible causes?

Tags: javascript, html, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm bamboozled. I use a select2 widget on a web page, implemented by django-autocomplete-light, and I attach an event listener to the it as follows:

```
const game_selector = $("#"+id_prefix+"game");
game_selector.on("change", switchGame);
```

Works a charm. I select a new game in the select box and the switchGame function is called.

That is running on Django development server with `manage.py runserver`. And I can see how groovy this is in Chrome's debugger:

[image]

There it is, switchGame(event) is the handler. And it all works too. No drama.

But I publish the code to my webserver and suddenly it doesn't work. The event listener never fires. switchGame is never called.

It's serving the self same code, looks the same in the client and in Chrome's debugger. All fine. I can even see the event listener is attached, albeit the order is different:

[image]

Served by the development server there there is a select2 handler above switchGame in the list and served from the production server the same select2 handler is listed below the switchGame handler.

Can the order matter? And why would the order differ?

In the end I am looking at the same binding code above, and I can set a breakpoint inside switchGame and cI can confirm served by the django runserver switchGame runs when I select a new game, but served from the production server it does not.

Suspect some jquery issue I even changed the listener binding to:

```
const game_selector = $("#"+id_prefix+"game");
//game_selector.on("change", switchGame);
game_selector.get(0).addEventListener("change", switchGame);
```

But the behaviour is the same. Bamboozles me how Javascript might function differently based on the server context? leads me to suspect different Javascript being served, but every check I have made speaks against that, as in I can make an edit, publish and reload web page from productions server and the changed javascript is there and visible in Chrome's debugger.

I wonder if anyone has ever experience such bizarre behaviour before and is in a position to comment or to suggest further diagnostic directions.

Comment: What basic debugging steps have you taken? For example, have you checked to see whether `game_selector` actually matches any elements?

Comment: _Can the order matter?_ - Yes, because the event handler is capturing during the capture phase rather than the bubble phase as shown in your images. It also appears that Select2 (`select2.full.js`) is not being loaded/invoked on the server. Look at the sources of those event handlers!!

Comment: @Pointy. Yep game_selector matches.As to debugging steps, more than I can summarise here, but still exploratory and it seems I overlooked a vital clue in my own study of bound events above that Randy spotted! Remember, this code all works on on box with one server and not on another with another server. A prime clue, and suggests it's environmental and impacting JS so included libs likely!

Comment: @Randy Casburn - brilliantly spotted and put me on the right track. I had overlooked that the eventhandler into select2.full.js was missing altogether. And have traced a likely cause if not solved it yet. But development machine has django-autocomplete-light 3.3.2 and production 3.3.4 and I found a known is issue with that widget here: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/1079, that I'd seen before and forgotten about ... but it looks like it relates to django-autocomplete-light and the order in which it loads included libs!

Comment: As it happens this is a nasty side efefct of loading the jquery library twice. I was loading it explicitly and a widget I was using loaded it again implicitly.  A bug! Discussed in depth here: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/1079 and not yet fixed, but workaround is that I don't load jquery explicitly any more!

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty side effect of loading the jQuery library twice.

I was loading it explicitly and a widget I was using loaded it again implicitly. A bug!

Discussed in depth here:

github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/1079

and not yet fixed, but workaround is that I don't load jQuery explicitly any more. And the issue disappears.

Sadly this does not explain the symptoms very well but it does provide a solution to what was being experienced. The same code was running in two contexts working in one and not the other. Remove the jQuery reload and it works in both.